# Automate Remote Window with with AutoIT

Tags: c#, ui-automation, dcom, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'd like to use AutoIT's COM interface in a C# application to automate a window on a remote machine.  I have code that looks like this:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoItX3.Control", "my-remote-server", true);
var automater = (IAutoItX3) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
automater.DoStuff();
```

The problem is that the automater doesn't seem to be recognizing windows on the remote machine. Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Is this even possible?

Comment: It seems like AutoIt isn't able to find windows in the currently logged in desktop session.

Answer (score 1):

this will only work if your c# application is sitting on the same machine as the app you want to control.
If you're using Remote Desktop, or Citrix etc, what you see on the screen is a bitmap of what the remote screen looks like, but when your C# app tries to find information about a window at certain coordinates, all there is is a bitmap.
One way to make it work would be to have your c# app on the remote machine, and using file messages in a shared folder or other methods to give it remote instructions.

Comment: Doesn't `COM` allow remote procedure calls ?